# Asp.net web api routing failed when deployed to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the follwing error after deploying to development server:
[image]

It works perfectly fine locally with Visual STudio's built in web server.

My client code:

```
function InsertAuditLog(category,operation,description) {
    var pagename = location.pathname.substring(1);
    var url = document.URL;
    $.post("../api/Audit", { Category: category, Operation: operation, PageName: pagename, Description: description, URLParameters: url });
}
```

My code in AuditController:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public void Post([FromBody]AuditLog log)
{
    SqlDatabase db = DBFactory.CreateDefault() as SqlDatabase;

    User user = (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserObject"];
    string loginName = user.LoginID;
    string appName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("appName").ToString();
    string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    try
    {
        db.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_insertAuditActivity", loginName, log.Category, log.Operation, log.PageName, log.Description, appName, DateTime.Now, log.URLParameters, sessionId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.ToString();
    }        
}
```

And my routing in Global.asax page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace XXXXConnection
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var route = RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            route.RouteHandler = new MyHttpControllerRouteHandler();
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

            if (null == authCookie)
            {
                //There is no authentication cookie.
                return;
            }
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
            try
            {
                authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Write the exception to the Event Log.
                return;
            }
            if (null == authTicket)
            {
                //Cookie failed to decrypt.
                return;
            }
            //When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
            //pipe-delimited string of group names.
            string[] groups = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });
            //Create an Identity.
            GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");
            //This principal flows throughout the request.
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, groups);
            Context.User = principal;
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    // Create two new classes
    public class MyHttpControllerHandler
        : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public MyHttpControllerHandler(RouteData routeData)
            : base(routeData)
        { }
    }
    public class MyHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(
            RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new MyHttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added IIS directory structure. This is deployed to the BC directory and it is configured as a apploication.
[image]

Here is the Fidler Raw View:

```
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYG2MIGzoAMKAQChCwYJKoZIgvcSAQICooGeBIGbYIGYBgkqhkiG9xIBAgICAG+BiDCBhaADAgEFoQMCAQ+ieTB3oAMCARKicARuZ7WMvTYV1BsYH+s3qBJvCdzflx48X3+tkjL64IIFl0s+8PWrDXXcIU+80mKKqJqTM+83Or/sArBiatNsLp4V9nkwBS6FzSbckAjMZP7YTvlI1ZBCaE7cbw1vpTppk8MbasxQPfN6HuL9U6P+3S4=
Date: Wed, 05 Feb 2014 17:30:43 GMT
Content-Length: 5169

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 7.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#CBE1EF;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 40px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
 border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px solid #969696; 
 border-bottom:1px solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.config_source{background:#fff5c4;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:normal;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{background-color:#ebebeb;} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error in Application "IDD/IDD/BC"</h1></div> 
<div id="server_version"><p>Internet Information Services 7.0</p></div> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><legend>Error Summary</legend> 
  <h2>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h2> 
  <h3>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><legend>Detailed Error Information</legend> 
  <div id="details-left"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>IIS Web Core</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>MapRequestHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>StaticFile</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>0x80070002</td></tr> 

   </table> 
  </div> 
  <div id="details-right"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>https://dsgxzdevspapp01:443/idd/bc/api/Audit</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>E:\wwwroot\IDD\BC\api\Audit</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>Negotiate</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>xxxx</td></tr> 

   </table> 
   <div class="clear"></div> 
  </div> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><legend>Most likely causes:</legend> 
  <ul>  <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>  <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>    <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><legend>Things you can try:</legend> 
  <ul>  <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser URL.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 


<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><legend>Links and More Information</legend> 
  This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again. 
  <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=404,0,0x80070002,6002">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 

 </fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Did you publish it to a virtual directory? Make sure you turned that directory into a web application.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question... What's with the `..` at the front of the URL you're posting to?

Comment: Ignore the dots ..  I was just trying different options.  With or without dots, it works with VS built in server locally.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is web application.  I will check to make sure.

Comment: You can get a 404 if any of the parameters are null.  Have you checked Fiddler to verify that all parameters are present?  Also, did you install the correct security in IIS?  From the error, it appears to be using "Negotiate" as the login method.  I've never used that, but I'd assume you need to install that as an option in IIS.  Also, look in the Event Log.  Sometimes it gives you a better description of the error.

Comment: @WinFXGuy How did you resolve the issue?